# How to remove time value in datetime-local input type?

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, datetimepicker

I am using `datetime-local` `input` type in HTML, but I don't want to use the time portion. I want to only get the date.

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="book_date" id="book_date">
```

This is the output I get from the `input` field:

```
2018-04-22T03:02
```

I want:

```
2018-04-22
```

Or how to remove the time portion from this value?

Comment: Why don't you just use a `date` field? FYI, this still isn't supported in Safari.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you only want the date portion, use `type="date"`:

```html
<input type="date" name="book_date" id="book_date"
       onchange="console.log(this.value);" />
```

If you really want to use `type="datetime-local"`, you can simply split the value by `T`:

```html
<input type="datetime-local" name="book_date" id="book_date"
       onchange="console.log(this.value.split('T')[0]);" />
```

Comment: You will see only date using type="date", but in actual if you try to catch that input say for example using angular, then it will display date and time both. You can use javascript substring method to remove time from this.

Comment: @AshleshSortee If you run my code snippet, you'll see that the value only contains the date, no time. I don't know what you're doing in your angular code, but you should fix that code instead of using the `substring` remedy.

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for date

```html
<input id="datetime" type="date" name="book_date" id="book_date">
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Form_%3Cinput%3E_types