# html5 input datetime-local: optional time is possible?

Tags: html, validation

I have this input field

```
<input type="datetime-local" required>
```

I would like the date part to be always required, but not the time part...
I tried with pattern, like

```
pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.*"
```

but it doesn't seem to work...
any idea...

Edit:
I explain better here

```html
<form name="test" method="POST" action="/">
  <input type="datetime-local" name="event_date_start" id="event_date_start"  
         min="2011-06-07T00:00" 
         max="2099-06-14T00:00" required><br>
  
  <input type="submit"/>
```

What I want is to use datetime, but time must be optional.
With the above example, submit is not allowed until you insert 00 in the time field..

I want to leave that optional...

Comment: Have a look at:https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_date.asp but not supported in IE < 11 and Safari

Comment: Here is another option--> https://stackoverflow.com/a/48919736/7124761

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for pattern just use the attributes min, max and value:

```
<input type="datetime-local"
value="2018-06-12T19:30"
min="2018-06-07T00:00"
max="2018-06-14T00:00" required>
```

If you want an inputfield with date only use:

```
<input type="date" required>
```

For time is optional:

```
<input type="date" required> <input type="time">
```

Comment: I edited and added a code snippet. I need datetime and min/max doesnt do the trick

Comment: Im not sure then if I understand what exactly you want to do.  You need an input field where you can input a date but not the time? Or do you need to be able to set the time, but its not required?

Comment: Added an extra line to my awnser, is that what you want? (<input type="date" required> <input type="time">)

Comment: oh, yes that's a nice workaround!! I want indeed to be able to set time but time is not required, while date is required.

Comment: The solution is in my awnser on the bottom so you can accept the awnser if it works for you :)