# Material UI datetime-local without minutes

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I have TextField with type = datetyme-local, but I don't need minutes in there. Is where any way to hide minutes?

```
<TextField
    label="From"
    type="datetime-local"
    InputLabelProps={{
        shrink: true,
    }}
/>
```

It looks so on my end:
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6NcP.png)

Comment: Use type="date" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48919671/how-to-remove-time-value-in-datetime-local-input-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is one has some issue so try the Material UI pickers library. here is the link https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/usage. The documentation is great.

Comment: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Comment: Link doesn't work. Can someone help, I have the same scenario to hide or disable minutes